# Make Family person type count as multiple persons in Woocommerce Bookings

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

Basically, here's one that's been puzzling me for a while and wondered if anyone fancied a go at it!!

We sell boat trip tickets on our website and I've run into a hurdle. For our new trip we're offering a family ticket (as a person type)

Problem is although a family is 4 people, the ticket would only count as one person, which would overbook the boat.

I have two option I can see:

- Somehow force woocommerce bookings to book off 4 slots for the one person type
  or
- Scrap the family ticket and automatically apply a discount based on have multiples of "2adults and 2children".

Been puzzling me for a while, and I cant see a way forward.

I purchased a conditional discount plugin, but although this will apply a discount based on multiple people, it doesn't take into consideration the "types" of people - so is no good unless it can be modified somehow.

Either way, I haven't got a clue how to go forwards.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using woo-commerce and WooCommerce bookings...    "So to resume you would like to make changes on a specific booking product (using Woocommerce bookings plugin) when added to cart (changing it from 1 person to 4 persons (2 adults and 2 children))...    That's exactly what I need - do you think there could be a way? 

Comment: Thank you Loic, but I have tried that - it just doesn't work mathematically with the other ticket options I have... it might help if I show you a link to the product? 

https://www.weferry.co.uk/book-online/sea-train/teignmouth-round-robin-departing-torquay